# shortcut to open file from the explorer into the editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I'm on the explorer, and select a file with the keyboard, then tap enter on keyboard, it proposes to rename the file. I would have expected this would open the file in the editor.

So how can I open a file selected with keyboard from the explorer, into the editor ? It seems an undocumented shortcut and I tried all combination of keys + enter.

(on mac osx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's cmd + down. 
What else should I say ?